# BindingNested List Property to Send to MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a view where I need to be able to select an item from a dropdown list and add it cumulatively to a list to display.  The only way I've been able to think to do this so far is to have a Property which binds to the Dropdownlist, send this back with the cumulative list and have the server add to the List and send it back for display.  This works well for the first item because the list to be added to has a `Count` of 0.  Any subsequent additions will cause the controller binding to wipe the List.

Here are the important parts of my code:

Model:

```
public class CaseAppealViewModel
{
    //needs to accumulate records as I add them and retain between server calls
    public List<CaseFile> SelectedCases
    {
        get { return _selectedCases; }
        set { _selectedCases = value; }
    }
    private List<CaseFile> _selectedCases = new List<CaseFile>();

    public Nullable<int> ChosenCase { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    @model MySystem.Models.CaseAppealViewModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddCase", "AppealLogs", Model))
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DisplayName("Cases:")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChosenCase, CaseAppealViewModel.CaseDropDownList, "", new {@class = "form-control"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCases)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Appeals)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="submit" id="AddCase" value="Add"/>
        </div>
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddCase(CaseAppealViewModel cavm)
{
     var tempCase = db.CaseFiles.Find(cavm.ChosenCase);
     if (tempCase != null)
     {
        cavm.SelectedCases.Add(db.CaseFiles.Find(cavm.ChosenCase));
     }
     return View("Details", cavm);
}
```

Is there a way I can send the `SelectedCases` List back and forth from the view to the controller without the `Count` resetting to 0?

Comment: No, not unless you were to create an input for each property of each `CaseFile` in the collection. But what would be the point - your not editing anything associated with `SelectedCases` so why would you want o degrade performance by sending it to the browser and then back again unchanged (and look at the `value` attribute of the html generated by `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCases)` to understand why that does not work

Comment: The value of the HTML makes sense why this would not work.  I believe I have figured out a way to implement the desired functionality using AJAX but I am now mostly curious how one would create a list of any sort using purely the .NET MVC framework which allows users to add (load from a database) and delete records that the client chooses without sending the entire list of chosen items to the backend as I wanted to do with SelectedCases